# Bootstrap datetimepicker without default initial value

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker I wanted to remove default selected date.

`$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({ format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', minDate:new Date() });`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `useCurrent:false` for your datetimepicer like

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var date = new Date();

     // subtract a day
     date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
     $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          useCurrent: false, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', minDate:date
     });
  });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2fjw57b/382/)

Comment: @DalinHuang subtract a day from current date to be min date

Comment: then you can pick yesterday or tomorrow, but not today cus useCurrent set to false

Comment: can i remove the below icon from the today's date as well?

Comment: i got it
`.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.today:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 7px 7px;
  border-bottom-color: #337ab7;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
}`

Comment: first time only useCurrent false will work not every time.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at their documentation you should be able to set useCurrent to false, which is true by default. *[Source](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent)*

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    minDate: new Date(),
    useCurrent: false
});
```

Comment: what if you want to pick 'today'... use moment()

Comment: can i also remove the below icon from the today's date as well?

Comment: thanks i got it. need to update in this class
`.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.today:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 7px 7px;
  border-bottom-color: #337ab7;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

if you print out `new Date()` you will understand it is a datetime, you should set as a date which you can use `(new Date()).toDateString()`

```
var datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  minDate: (new Date()).toDateString()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/0Ltv25o8/4795/

or you can use moment js to set the minDate...
if you use `useCurrent: false` will exclude 'Today' so use moment or find the 'day' yourself.

```
var datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  minDate: moment().startOf('day')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/0Ltv25o8/4793/

Answer (score 0):

```
I used two dates between these dates validating using datetimepicker.

   if ($("#toDate").val() != "") {
      $("#toDate").datetimepicker("destroy");
  }
  var fromDateFilt = new Date();
  if ($("#frmDate").val().length != 0) {
      fromDateFilt = this.convertDate($("#frmDate").val())
  }
  $('#toDate').datetimepicker({
      widgetPositioning: {
          horizontal: 'left'
      },
      icons: {
          time: "fa fa-clock-o",
          date: "fa fa-calendar",
          up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
          down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
          previous: 'fa fa-arrow-left',
          next: 'fa fa-arrow-right'
      },
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      minDate: fromDateFilt,
      maxDate: new Date()
  });
  this.psaReportForm.controls['frmDate'].setValue($("#frmDate").val());

public convertDate(date) {
  let dateArry = date.split("-");
  return new Date(dateArry[2], dateArry[1] - 1, dateArry[0]);
}
```

Comment: if you are using minDate or maxDate option it will take automatic today value.